# php static property

Tags: php, class, static

I have two code snippets (regarding the `static` keyword) which I expect them to have same output, but actually the outputs are different.

The question is why?

**Snippet 1**

```
class base
{
    public static $var = 1;
}

class sub extends base
{
    public static $var = 2;
}

echo base::$var; // Outputs 1
```

> 1

**Snippet 2**

```
class base2
{
    public static $var2 = 1;
}

class sub2 extends base2
{
}

sub2::$var2 = 2;
echo base2::$var2; // Outputs 2
```

> 2

Comment: thanks for the tip, just updated

Comment: I suspect you are confusing the result with `const`. In php `static` defines a property that is independent of an instance. But it can still change.

Comment: @user1970939, what are you actually trying to accomplish? The output is different because you removed `public static $var = 2;`. But you know that. So what's the real question?

Comment: I think your looking for: In class sub use: self::$var = 2;

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would like to add one more point to it.

STATIC variable are **not** associated to any particular instance/object of a class. Hence you modify the variable with Parent Class reference or Child Class reference, the same copy gets modified.

Hence apart from understanding Public Static as Global, Please understand it as not associated to any particular instance, hence with any class hierarchy reference you update a static variable , same memory location gets updated.

--

Vinod

Comment: so as per ur explanation if i change the value of the var in class sub of first code like this sub::$var = 3; it will update the value of var in class base?

Comment: Yes, That's true. Try it out.

Comment: no,it does not:      class base {
    public static $var = 1;
}
class sub extends base {
    public static $var = 2;
}
sub::$var = 3;
echo base::$var;
echo sub::$var; please try this

Comment: @zamil Well, i was saying w.r.t your code2 sample that you written as part of your question. If you don't have a variable defined in child class and refer the parent class static variable with the child class name like sub::$var, then if will update the parent's copy. If you have same variable name defined both in each class, then they update only their local copy. My comment was w.r.t to your code2 sample only

Answer (score 9):

`Public static variable` acts like `global` variable.

As the scope of `public static variable` lies globally, you can ensure that any changes to the `global variable` can be seen across the program.This concept, you can analyze in your sample program....

Please have look in [Static variable inheritance](http://globalconstant.scnay.com/2009/12/14/static-variable-inheritance-in-php/).

Answer (score 4):

If you pass a static variable to a subclass, then this variable is shared (it always has the same value in both classes). If you overwrite the static variable in a subclass, then its a new static variable independent of the static variable from the parent.

In **Snippet 1** `base::var` and `sub::var` have different memory allocations, because you defined `$var = 2;` in the class `sub`.

In **Snippet 2** `base::var` and `sub::var` have the same memory allocation, because you did not specify `$var2` in the class `sub2`.

Thats why `base:var` is not changing. It would also not change if you change `$var` from `sub` class later like this:

```
class base
{
    public static $var = 1;
}

class sub extends base
{
    public static $var = 2;
}
sub::var = 3
echo base::var; // Outputs 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the sub2 class does not have var2 it takes the value of the base2 class.So when u assigned a new value using this `sub2::$var2 = 2;` it changed to new value.

In first code you have overridden that in your extended class.Both variable have scope inside their respective classes.

Comment: It's wrong, there is no concept of over riding for static variables/methods. It's just the same shared memory. Please refer my comment

Comment: we can definitely override static methods.But not sure about static properties,but if u declare same variable as parent class in an extended class they don't point to the same memory location.

Comment: Agreed, Please see my comments to your previous question in my answer