# How to access static properties of a class

Tags: php, laravel

I've looked at answers of stack overflow, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930046/php-static-property), but nothing has worked and I feel like it's so simple! I don't understand.

I have my file in `/app/C/V1/RM.php:`

```
<?php

namespace App\C\V1;

class RM{
    public static $info = [
        key => 'rm',
        name => 'RM Title Here',
        logo => '',
        status => 'alpha'
    ];
}
```

I'm trying to get `$info` in a Laravel controller like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\C\V1;

class CourierApiV1Controller extends Controller
{    
    public function listC(Request $request) {
        $info = V1\RM::info;
        return response()->json([
            'info' => $info
        ]);
    }
}
```

Why is this not working? How can I get a static property?

Comment: what errors do you get ?

Comment: Use of undefined constant key - assumed 'key' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `single quote` OR `double  quote` for the array index, by default they are treated as const that why you are getting error

```
class RM{
 public static $info = [
    'key' => 'rm',
    'name' => 'RM Title Here',
    'logo' => '',
    'status' => 'alpha'
 ];
}
```

Comment: yup, this was it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to add $ to call static properties

```
RM::$info
```

Comment: I get this error when I try that: `Use of undefined constant key - assumed 'key' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)`

Comment: But that's because your code is a total mess full of errors, and this one has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Amarnasan care to elaborate?

Comment: @Amarnasan missing a couple quotes around array keys isn't 'a mess full of errors' by any definition